# Google calendar API create group calendar events

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

My goal is to insert events to a group calendar VIA PHP

1. I have created an app on api console
2. I have activated calendar API and created API KEY
3. I have created a service account [as described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Here is my code:

```
class Googl_Cal{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->client = $this->get_client();
    }

    public function get_client()
    {

       putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/' . dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/gcal_service_account.json');
       $client = new Google_Client();
       $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
       $scopes = [ Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR ];
       $client->setScopes($scopes);

       return $client;
    }

    public function create_event(){

       $service = new Google_Service_Calendar( $this->client );

       $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

       $calendarId = '';

       $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(
            array(
                'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
                'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
                'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
                'start' => array(
                    'dateTime' => '2018-01-31T09:00:00-07:00',
                    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Jerusalem',
                ),
                'end' => array(
                    'dateTime' => '2018-01-31T17:00:00-07:00',
                    'timeZone' => 'Asia/Jerusalem',
                ),
                'recurrence' => array(
                    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
                ),
                'reminders' => array(
                    'useDefault' => FALSE,
                    'overrides' => array(
                        array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                        array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );

       $calendarId = 'primary';

       $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

       print_r($event);
       die();
    }
}
```

After calling create_event(); 
Im getting an empty list on $calendarList

Comment: "After calling create_event(); Im getting an empty list on $calendarList" . We can't see what you're doing after you call create_event, so no idea what $calendarList looks like in that context. _Within_ create_event(), it just forms a list of the available calendars, it's not a list of events. And in any case you request it but don't actually use it for anything. Bit confusing to those reading, all in all.

Comment: This question was answered correctly by DaImTo... thankyou

Comment: Ok but it's hard to see how, because your code as seen above already contains the variable value change made in DalmTo's suggestion, and you don't seem to have edited the question to update the code. Your code already contains a line to set `$calendarId = 'primary';`, and you do this before you make any use of that variable. So I fail to see what possible functional difference could be made by setting it any earlier. What have I missed?

Comment: The latter of his solution starting... "assuming you want it...." was the thing that helped me..  I shared the calendar with the service account and updated $calendarId to the group calendar ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a service account is not you you will be inserting into the service accounts calendar.

I suspect part of your issue is that you are not inserting it into a calendar and are probably getting an error.

> $calendarId = '';

I sugest you do

> $calendarId = 'primary';

This will insert into the service accounts primary calendar.

Assuming you want it writing to one of your personal calendars.  Take the service account email address and share the calendar with it in the Web google calendar app.   It will then be able to write to it.   Tip grab the calendar id out of the web site while you are at it as calendarlist.list isnt going to return it until you add it, this is an annoying feature in service accounts.

Comment: $calendarId isn't used in the code until after it's already been reassigned to have the value "primary" (i.e. `$calendarId = 'primary';

       $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);` - before these lines the $calendarId variable is not actually called upon), so it's hard to see how this is the issue. Have I missed something?